# How to Select a value in tkinter Listbox by pressing key

Tags: python, tkinter, listboxitem

I have Listbox with limited values. I want to select List Item by pressing first letter of item in Listbox. I have tryed Listbox.select_set but its not working. Here is my code:-

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.geometry("750x250")

def select_key(event):

    for itm in range(List_Prem_Province.size()):
        if event.keysym.upper() == List_Prem_Province.get(itm)[:1]:
            List_Prem_Province.select_set(itm)
            break


List_Prem_Province = Listbox(win, exportselection=0, height=1, font=(
    'Bell', 14, 'bold'))

List_Prem_Province.insert(1, "Balochistan")
List_Prem_Province.insert(2, "Federal Govt")
List_Prem_Province.insert(3, "Gilgit-Baltistan")
List_Prem_Province.insert(4, "Khyber Pakhtunkhwa")
List_Prem_Province.insert(5, "Punjab")
List_Prem_Province.insert(6, "Sindh")
List_Prem_Province.bind('<KeyPress>', select_key)
List_Prem_Province.grid(
    column=5, row=6, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `List_Pem_Province.see(itm)` before `break` inside `select_key()` function.

Comment: or you want to display only matching works in list box like suggestion box

Comment: @acw1668 thats worked. Thanks!. But kindly describe why only List_Prem_Province.select_set(itm) is not working and what does List_Prem_Province.see(itm) do?

Comment: `.select_set()` just add the item into selection list, `.see()` make the specified item within viewable area.